# Cardinal of the set of real functions

Tags: functions, cardinals

We know that the cardinal of natural numbers is $\aleph_0$, and the cardinal of real numbers is $\mathfrak c$. Is it correct that the cardinal of real functions is $2^{\mathfrak c}$?

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is infinite, the set of functions from $X$ to $X$ has size $|X|^{|X|}=2^{|X|}$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo <insert usual AC nitpick here>?  (As a question because I presume the equivalency can't be proven even for $X=2^{\aleph_0}$ but I'm far from 100% certain - although given that OP talks about the _cardinality_ of the reals, assuming AC seems eminently reasonable.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Without choice, if $X\times X\sim X$, then $X^X\sim 2^X$, because $$|X^X|\le (|2^X|)^{|X|}=2^{|X\times X|}=|2^X|\le |X^X|.$$ This applies to $X=\mathbb R$, of course. But yes, without choice it is consistent that there are infinite sets $X$ with $|X^X|>|2^X|$. This happens, for example, if $\mathcal P(X)$ is infinite and Dedekind-finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that it has at least that cardinality. Consider the map:

$$ \Psi : 2^{\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow \{f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \} $$

given by $\Psi(S) = \chi_S(x)$ where $\chi_S(x) = 1$ if $x \in S$ and $\chi_S(x) = 0$ if $x \not\in S$. Note that $\Psi$ is injective, so you know that $2^{ |\mathbb{R}|} \leq |\{f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \}|$. Now you just need to get an upper bound on $ |\{f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \}|$.